# Karma testing controller that calls service with http

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Can someone please tell me the best way to run tests on my controller function getData and the factory function too. I've very confused and don't know where to start. How would you write tests for the code below?

```
myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'myFactory', function ($scope, myFactory) {

    $scope.getData = function(id) {
        var promise = myFactory.GetData('/dta/GetData?Id=' + id);
        promise
        .then(function (success) {
            $scope.result = success;
        }, function (error) {
            $scope.error = true;
        });
    }
});


myApp.factory('myFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        GetData: function (url) {
            return $http.get(url)
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
             }, function (error) {
                return error;
             });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: What do you want to test, your controller's `getData` method or your factory's `GetData` method?

Comment: ... for the former, you would [create a mock (spy)](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_<code>createSpyObj</code>) of `myFactory`. For the latter, use [`$httpBackend`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend)

Comment: I would like to test all the code seen above. I'm not sure what an experienced tester would do.

Comment: When testing the controller getData function, am I using $httpBackend as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to test each component in isolation (that's what unit tests are for). So something like this for the controller

```
describe('myController test', () => {
    let scope, myFactory;

    beforeEach(() => {
        myFactory = jasmine.createSpyObj('myFactory', ['GetData']);            

        module('your-module-name');
        inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();

            $controller('myController', {
                $scope: scope,
                myFactory: myfactory
            });
        });
    });

    it('getData assigns result on success', inject(function($q) {
        let id = 1, success = 'success';
        myFactory.GetData.and.returnValue($q.when(success));

        scope.getData(id);
        expect(myFactory.GetData).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/dta/GetData?Id=' + id);
        scope.$digest(); // resolve promises
        expect(scope.result).toBe(success);
    }));

    it('getData assigns error on rejections', inject(function($q) {
        myFactory.GetData.and.returnValue($q.reject('error'));

        scope.getData('whatever');
        scope.$digest();
        expect(scope.error).toEqual(true);
    }));
});
```

For your factory, you would create a separate `describe` and inject and configure [`$httpBackend`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/%24httpBackend). There are plenty of example in the documentation.

---

FYI, you should omit the error handler in your factory, ie

```
return $http.get(url).then(response => response.data);
```

or if you don't like ES2015

```
return $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
    return response.data;
});
```

as you are currently converting a failed request into a successful promise.

---

In fact, I'd go a bit further to make your `GetData` factory more useful than a mere `$http` wrapper

```
GetData: function(id) {
    return $http.get('/dta/GetData', {
        params: { Id: id }
    }).then(function(res) {
        return res.data;
    });
}
```

Comment: I've modified my factory to be GetData: function (url) {return $http.get(url);} But now the line expect(scope.result).toBe(success); doesn't work. I'm not sure what this should now be.

Comment: @user1024941 you seem to have missed the part where the promise resolves with `response.data`. This shouldn't have changed your test though

Comment: why do I need the then clause in the service, when I can have it in my controller and access success.data?

Comment: @user1024941 it makes more sense in the service as it encapsulates the `$http` part. If consumers of the service only need the data and not any other properties on the HTTP response object, you should just resolve the promise with the data only. If you insist on extracting the data in your controller, you'll have to change your test to `$q.when({data: success})` in order for the resolved value to have a `data` property